# Jquery div selector for a particular row

Tags: jquery, css, closest

I have the following li as rows.. My requirement is when i click on delete anchor, popup div should appear.

```
<li class="select">
  <div class="data_options"><a href="#" class="itemDelete">DELETE</a> </div> 
<!-- row hover options here-->
      <!-- popup starts here-->
    <div class="data_popup data_delete"><span class="tip"></span>Are you sure want to delete this file?
  </div>
 <!-- popup ends here--> 
  <div class="cfix"></div>
</li>
```

I tried this but it is affecting the whole rows. I need the popup only in a particular row.

```
$('.itemDelete').live('click', function() {
$('.data_delete').slideToggle('medium');
});
```

and this does not even work.

```
$('.itemDelete').live('click', function() {
$this.closest('.data_delete').slideToggle('medium');
});
```

Please help me.

Comment: This particular issue has been solved. If you have another problem you should ask another question. You can of course add a link to this question for reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `this` to refer to the one that's clicked on and then search only in the parent `li`:

```
$('.itemDelete').live('click', function() {
    $(this).closest("li").find('.data_delete').slideToggle('medium');
});
```

Using things like `.closest("li")` and `.find('.data_delete')` makes your code much less dependent upon the exact HTML structure you have.  This finds whatever `li` you're in and then searches it for the `.data_delete` in that `li`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.itemDelete').live('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().next('.data_delete').slideToggle('medium');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace $this by $(this) first :

```
$('.itemDelete').live('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('.data_delete').slideToggle('medium');
});
```

That should work better ;).

Comment: actually, i have done the same thing. tying mistake here. this method does not work.

Comment: This won't work as the `.data_delete` is further down in the DOM tree and not up.